# Mongoid::Errors::MixedRelations: Mongoid + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I have a Model User from Devise with that relations:

user.rb

```
# Relationships  
references_many :houses, :dependent => :delete
```

Now I have a Model House created with scaffold:

house.rb

```
# Relationships
referenced_in :user, :inverse_of => :houses 
embeds_many :deals
```

Now I have a Model Deal with this relations:

```
embedded_in :house, :inverse_of => :deals
```

In my routes.rb I have:

```
resources :houses do
  resources :deals
end
```

When I try get the user that make the deal in console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > User.first.deals.first
```

I get the next error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::MixedRelations: Referencing a(n) Deal document from the User document via a relational association is not allowed since the Deal is embedded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you provided, an user is not directly related to a deal.

It seems that you tried to do :

```
class User
  [...]
  references_many :houses, :dependent => :delete
  references_many :deals
end

class Deal
  [...]
  embedded_in :house
  referenced_in :user
end
```

As your Deals are embedded into Houses, you can't access them directly from Users through a relation.
It is a known limitation of Mongoid.

You can use :

```
@houses_that_match = House.where("deals.user_id" => @user.id)
@deals = []
@houses_that_match.each do |house|
  @deals += house.deals.select { |deal| deal.user == @user }
end
```